# Qt. Access application ts file from JS code (context menu translated texts)

Tags: javascript, qt, contextmenu, translation

In my application I have some .ts files for languages in my application resources, so I access translations with tr("") from a C++ class, and with qsTr("") from a QML file

I also have a WebEngineView + WebChannel, with a custom HTML file and JS files associated.

In this JS code, I have a custom context menu:
https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html#example-html-simple-context-menu

Using the 'build' callback, I can set a name dinamically every time my menu is open:

```
$(document).contextMenu({
      selector: 'span.context-menu',
      build: function($triggerElement, e){
          return {
              items: {
                 copy: {  name: [text depending on the language]
                 ...
```

My problem is how to access to my .ts files from this JS code. For example, I need context menu translated texts

Thanks in advance,
Diego

Comment: js or HTML does not allow translations?

Comment: If you can access the Qt object maybe it is possible with this function: [http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qtTrId]